# jQuery not formatting html right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can upload a picture of the problem if you need one, but I need the last item to look like the rest. I read an rss feed and grab the first title, then populate it in the list. I try to format it like the rest, but it is not working. Here is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {

    jQuery.getFeed({
        url: 'xml/rss-21.xml',
        success: function(feed) {

            var html = '';

            for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

                var item = feed.items[i];


                html += '<li data-theme="c">'
                + '<a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">'
                + item.link
                + '">'
                + item.title
                + '</a>'
                + '</li>';
            }

            jQuery('#result').append(html);
        }    
    });
});

</script>
```

I need it to formatted like:

```
<li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="http://www.tristateis.com" data-transition="slide">
                        Win a Free Digital Pocket Memo
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show us what you're getting ?

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/y0nyv4tin/

Comment: I'm at work so i can't see it because of the network restrictions, can you just add the code of what you're getting ?

Comment: Hey Isaac I got it to format correctly, I was leaving out some css. However it is not working in chrome, but it is working in safari. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens in safari that doesn't in chrome ?

Comment: In safari it adds the elements to the list, looks great, but in chrome it does not add them at all. I am getting an error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/morningside/Downloads/eclipse/TSES%20Mobile/assets/www/xml/rss-21.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: What happens it's that for security reasons and the way chrome treats pages you are get some limitations in `ajax` requests from local files, if you can run this on a local server or run chrome disabling web security http://www.senchatouchbits.com/7/cross-domain-ajax-requests.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not actually making a link here, the href should be item.link (assuming that's the correct value)

```
html += '<li data-theme="c">'
        + '<a href="' + item.link +'" data-transition="slide">'
        + item.title
        + '</a>'
        + '</li>';
```

Comment: Your right, I just need the title to be displayed not the link. I forgot to take that out in my original post. I copy your text above but I still does not look like the rest of the elements in my list. Here is what it looks like: http://postimage.org/image/y0nyv4tin/

Comment: in that case it looks like there's probably some class missing that the others have.  The html it produces is valid.  You can right click on one of the other links and choose inspect element in chrome and it will show all the styles / properties that the tag has

Comment: Thank you! I inspected the element and found out what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be on when you're appending to `html` :

```
html += '<li data-theme="c">'
            + '<a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">'
            + item.link
            +" "               
            + item.title
            + '</a>'
            + '</li>';
```

Also what you can do to get more control than just formatting a string is to do this:

```
var li = $('<li></li>',{
   'data-theme' : 'c',
});

var link = $('<a></a>',{
    href : item.link
    text : item.title,
    'data-transition' : 'slide'
});
```

And then just `li.append(a);` that way it's easier to edit and it's also a better practice

Answer (score 1):

```
html += '<li data-theme="c">'
+ '<a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">'
+ item.link
+ '">' // problem here
+ item.title
+ '</a>'
+ '</li>';
```

should be

```
html += '<li data-theme="c">'
+ '<a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">'
+ item.link
+ item.title
+ '</a>'
+ '</li>';
```

**EDIT:**

you need to put the link in the right place:

```
html += '<li data-theme="c">'
+ '<a data-transition="slide" href="'
+ item.link + '" >'
+ item.title
+ '</a>'
+ '</li>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, but it is still not working correctly, tried both solutions. The text is in the ul,but still not formatted correctly.

Comment: you should probably remove the first href="#page1" then

Comment: I used your edit, but it looks the same. I do not need item.link, I can just use #page1. Can I use the theme in my jQuery Function?